# Does anyone have any link to the original papers describing MSK144 and JT4?

Tags: digital-modes

I am looking for the original papers describing both MSK144 and JT4 protocols. I can easily find the corresponding papers for some other digital modes such as JT65 or FT8 (mainly at the Princeton Physics website), but no information about these protocols.

It would be great if anyone could provide me any link or reference to the original publications.

Thank you in advance.
73.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WSJT User Guide version 2.0.0](http://physics.princeton.edu/pulsar/k1jt/wsjtx-doc/wsjtx-main-2.0.0.html), which is hosted at the Princeton Physics website, was written by Joe Taylor W1JT himself, who wrote much of the WSJT code.  In the Protocol Specifications chapter there are links to QEX articles and other references, including one about the JT65 protocol.

Given Professor Taylor's academic background, to me it seems safe to say that if there is no reference or link to an article or paper in the User Guide for a particular protocol, then no more authoritative article or paper exists.  In that case, the User Guide, other cited references, and the [published source code for WSJT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wsjt/) probably are the most definitive references.